# C# Application not starting in a single PC

Tags: c#, startup

I have an application that runs on a large number of PC's. In a single computer it doesn't start and the windows event viewer produces the following log (which was sent to me by the Client):

> Log Name:      Application Source:        .NET Runtime Date:
>   11/10/2018 17:00:31 Event ID:      1026 Task Category: None Level:
>   Error Keywords:      Classic User:          N/A Computer:      PCName
>   Description: Application: MyApp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean) 
>   at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
>   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
>   at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(System.String)
>
> Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
>   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
>   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.get_UseLegacySerializerGeneration()
>   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[],
>   System.Type[], System.String, System.String,
>   System.Security.Policy.Evidence)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GetSerializersFromCache(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[],
>   System.Type)    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMapping[],
>   System.Type)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientType..ctor(System.Type)    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol..ctor()    at
>   CrashReporterDotNET.com.drdump.HttpsCrashReporterReportUploader..ctor()
>   at CrashReporterDotNET.DrDump.DrDumpService..ctor()    at
>   CrashReporterDotNET.CrashReport.SendAnonymousReport()    at
>   CrashReporterDotNET.CrashReport..ctor(CrashReporterDotNET.ReportCrash)
>   at CrashReporterDotNET.ReportCrash.Send(System.Exception)    at
>   MyApp.App.ReportCrash(System.Exception, System.String)    at
>   MyApp.App.CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException(System.Object,
>   System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)

Similar threads were not relevant as my app.config file was found to be different.

EDIT: This is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.10.0" newVersion="2.6.10.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.2.29.0" newVersion="2.2.29.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <userSettings>
    <MyApp.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="MySettings1" serializeAs="String">
        <value>1</value>
      </setting>
      ........
      ........
      <setting name="MySettings15" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
    </MyApp.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" /></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: And you've ensured the configure file on the affected machine is byte for byte identical to a working machine. Even including byte order marks identical?

Comment: `app.config`? Which `app.config`? The error points to a problem with `app.config` but you forgot to include it in your question. It's relevant.

Comment: Caius - I wasn't aware that there is a configuration file on the machine. where is the relevant file? spender - I've added the app.config file now.